# What do I have to read/watch to understand the story of the Super Dragon Ball Heroes manga?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-heroes

Is the new Super Dragon Ball Heroes manga understandable by its own, or do you have to read and/or watch Dragon Ball Super and/or the previous Dragon Ball Heroes manga to understand its story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say read Dragon ball heroes because it is not in line with the actual dragon ball it is a different story but with the same characters it is a multiverse story